# What is the difference between operating voltage and output voltage in power electronics?

Tags: power-electronics

I am currently working on the topic of multilevel inverters.  When I started studying about it I came across the term operating voltage. When I went to search about it I got this doubt that whether these two terms are same or different.

I searched in the internet but couldn't find it.

Is operating and output voltage related to the same meaning or are they different?

Comment: Operating voltage is usually a range of input voltages for a device that guarantees  the specified output voltage. example: a DC power supply, operating voltage 95 VAC to 240 VAC, output voltage: 12 VDC.

Answer (score 1):

Operating voltage could be the input voltage. Output voltage would be, well, output voltage.

For example, the operating voltage of my inverter is 12V - 24V DC. the output voltage is 200V AC.